# Breakdown of indexOf function

Tags: indexof

Can someone explain this solution to me?  A friend helped me, but he just wrote it all out and didn't explain it. Now, I'm really confused :(

```
_.indexOf = function(array, target){
    var result = -1;
    _.each(array, function(item, index) {
  if (item === target && result === -1) {
    result = index;
  }
});

return result;
```

};

```
return result;
```

};

Comment: what i'm trying to do is rewrite indexOf using _.each

Comment: Sounds like your friend is a real jerk. Other than writing that for you. Does it work?

Comment: what is the underscore referring to? This is Javascript, correct?

Comment: What "solution" are you referring to? Do you understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The function traverses through all the elements of the array and returns index of the first element that is equal to target. The code could also look like this:

```
_.indexOf = function(array, target){
    var result = -1;
    _.each(array, function(item, index) {
        if (item === target) {
            result = index;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```